# Loading Animation for GridView's

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, animation, loading

I have a dashboard like interface for the ASP.NET (C#) application I am developing . There are a few GridView's on this page that take awhile to query all the data from the database. The GridView's just display data. Is there a way I can load the page and just display a loading icon for each of this GridView's while they load?

Thanks.

Comment: Are you referring to when you make ajax calls to load the data or on page load?

Comment: On page load. Ideally I'd like to display an animation for the time it takes for the GridView to return the data. Since each GridView will run for a different amount of time.

Answer (score 3):

You can try something like the following:

1. Place all of your GridViews inside of Update Panels
2. Do not bind them on page load
3. Place a timer on the page inside an update panel and set it to trigger 500ms after the page loads
4. Now, bind your GridViews

Combine the above with the [AJAX Toolkit UpdatePanel Animation Extender](http://www.asp.net/ajax/ajaxcontroltoolkit/samples/UpdatePanelAnimation/UpdatePanelAnimation.aspx) and you'll have what you're looking for.

This will make it appear as if your GridViews are being loaded dynamically AFTER the page loads and your users will see loading icons notifying them.

You can also see a full working (similar) example [here](http://mattberseth.com/blog/2007/07/delay_load_an_updatepanel.html).